# i have error in my get method its show me 404 error .net core and angular

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, .net-core

The problem when i send request to api
in my api my post methd and getAllUsers its work but
the GetUser method doesn't work its show me 404 error i was trying to solve it i used many route but still this problem
so if any one can help me to solve this problem this is my api code:

```
 [EnableCors("MyPolicy")]
    [Route("api/Login")]
    [ApiController]
    public class LoginController : ControllerBase
    {
        
       
        [EnableCors("MyPolicy")]
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<User> GetAllUsers()
        {
            IUserRepository obj = new UserRepository();
            return obj.GetAll();
        }

        [Route("api/Login/GetUser/{id?}")]
        [HttpGet]
        public User GetUser(int id)
        {
            IUserRepository obj = new UserRepository();
            return obj.Get(id);

        }


        [HttpPost]
        public User PostAddUser(User item)
         {
            IUserRepository obj = new UserRepository();
            return obj.Add(item);
        }
```

and this is my service in angular :

```
Load(id:number){
        debugger;
        return  this.httpcli.get("https://localhost:44366/api/Login/GetUser?id="+id);


    }
```

and this my startup.cs in core api :

```
      public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy(name: "MyPolicy", builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyMethod().AllowAnyHeader()));    

            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "LoginApi", Version = "v1" });
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
           

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseCors("MyPolicy");

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the action attribute routing:

```
           [Route("~/api/Login/GetUser/{id?}")]
           public User GetUser(int id)
        {
            IUserRepository obj = new UserRepository();
            return obj.Get(id);

        }
```

and url too:

```
this.httpclient.get("https://localhost:44366/api/Login/GetUser/"+id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to send a path parameter instead of a request parameter:

```
Load(id:number){
        debugger;
        return  this.httpcli.get(`https://localhost:44366/api/Login/GetUser/${id}`);


    }
```